# In ASP.NET is it dangerous to get a URL via URL?

Tags: asp.net, validation, url

It's possible to get a string via `Request.QueryString.Get("url")` but ASP.NET raises an exception: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected frfom the client".
I'm not gonna trust this url for any purpose (for example just redirecting client to that url). Am I supposed to change my design or simply turn off the ASP.NET exception ? How to suppress this validation ?

Comment: The login redirect uses this as well, just make sure it's HTML Encoded.

Comment: I was planning not to encode it for readability by users, then they can change it easily. What then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its as dangerous as any other form as user input really. depends on what you're going to use it for.

asp.net will try to restrict certain possible 'mistakes' you might make, in this case its doing request validation, to prevent possible XSS etc, and try to save you from yourself. you can of course override this `<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>`, but you're going to need to *really* make sure you dont introduce a security issue in your system now.